# Helmholtz solved on cylindrical coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am trying to solve for magnetic fields on the axis of a single loop Helmholtz coil using the Biot-Savart Law and a cylindrical coordinate system. I have some point on the axis defined as
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For some distance $a$ away from the centre of the coil on the axis. The length element should be
$$
dL=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
Rd\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

for some coil radius $R$. The $r$ vector pointing from $P$ to the length element should be

$$
r=\begin{pmatrix}
R\\
\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}-P=\begin{pmatrix}
R\\
\theta\\
-a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But if I do the cross product of $dL\times r$, the first element becomes $-aRd\theta$ which does not disappear when integrating $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. This would mean there is some magnetic field in the radial direction. That doesn't seem right. Can anyone spot the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the column vector notation you've used doesn't really make sense. For example, if I write down a vector $\mathbf{v} = (a, b, c)$ which is meant to have a component in the $r$-direction and the $\theta$-direction, you'd have no idea what vector I'm talking about because these directions are different for different points!

Comment: For example, your formulas suggest the line element has position vector $\mathbf{p} = (R, \theta, 0)$. This isn't right; it has coordinates $(R, \theta, 0)$. To see the distinction, imagine increasing $\theta$ by $2\pi$. The coordinates are the same, so we're describing the same point, but the column vector you've written would be different.

Comment: This distinction between coordinates and components of a position vector can be ignored in cartesian coordinates, which is probably where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product $\mathbf{dL}\times\mathbf{r}$ has a component $-aR\,d\theta\,\hat{r}(\theta)$, where $\hat{r}(\theta)$ is the unit vector in the radial direction for a line element with angular coordinate $\theta$. Crucially, note that the "radial direction" is different at different $\theta$, and this has to be taken into account in the integration:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} -aR\,\hat{r}(\theta)\,d\theta = -aR\int_0^{2\pi} \hat{r}(\theta)\,d\theta = 0.$$

This means the total magnetic field only has a component along $z$, as is required by symmetry. In other words, each line element produces a radial magnetic field, but those radial components point in every direction perpendicular to $z$ so cancel out.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That's very helpful.